# Copy data from several workbooks with greek \ unicode caracters in one workbook

Tags: excel, unicode, find, vba

I have data in several workbooks in greek and I need to paste them in a single workbook. Example of the data:

ΚΑΘΑΡΟ  5314.96 4870.76

The problem is that using the "Find" in VBA doesn't seem to recognize greek characters even when usin ChrW().

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem (although its was really painful). When coding in VBA you can input greek characters in the search field this way for example:

```
ChrW(922) & ChrW(913) & ChrW(920)
```